# how to update all rows of a sequence in postgres with a start value of U0000DGF and incrementing in postgres

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I have a table in postgres of which all rows of a column has sequence to be updated with a starting value of U0000DGF and incrementing by 1.

I tried to find something similar online but wasn't able to get anything useful. postgres and PL/SQL is not my expertise. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the result of the expression "U0000DGF + 1"? What about "U0000ZZZ + 1"? "U9999ZZZ + 1" What have you tried?

Comment: i have column have sequence with DGF0001 auto increment i want to update to U0DGF0001 +1 because i have 13 company  in consolidation and it s unique per company i want to change it to not have duplicate key constaraint

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)